# How to get precision (number of digits past decimal) from a Ruby BigDecimal object?

Tags: ruby

Given the following expression for a new `BigDecimal` object:

```
b = BigDecimal.new("3.3")
```

How can I get the precision that has been defined for it? I would like to know a method that will return `1`, as there is 1 digit after the decimal. I'm asking this because `b.precision` or `b.digits` don't work.

---

[Thanks to Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378504/rails-bigdecimal-how-to-get-the-precision-or-the-number-of-digits#comment41412399_26378504), a method name for dealing with such information is [`BigDecimal#precs`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-precs). Given that a `BigDecimal` object comes from a database, I don't know the precision of that database object. I have tried the following, but it does not seem useful for my situation.

```
b = BigDecimal.new(3.14, 2)
b.precs
=> [18, 27]
```

How can I retrieve the `2` information/argument?

Comment: Are you guessing these method names? Hint: [BigDecimal#precs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-precs) :)

Comment: no, i simply get lost in the documentation.However, i've updated the question to be more precise

Comment: @AgostinoX I have attempted to edit your question, most notably removing "Rails" from the title. If possible, please list the version of Ruby you are using. Also, In the first example, do you intend to have `"3.3"` as a string argument?

Comment: @HunterStevens BigDecimal will accept a string

Comment: @WayneConrad Just reading that now. Thank you!

Comment: @AgostinoX I edited your question today, because from the wording, it looked like you wanted the number of digits _after_ the decimal. Is that what you want, or the significant digits (number of sig digits before and after decimal) instead? Feel free to rollback my edits or such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 2.2.2 (and, I'm guessing, in prior versions), you can't get
back the precision that was given to [BigDecimal::new](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-new).  That's
because it is used in some computations; only the result of those
computations is stored.  This doc comment is a clue:

> The actual number of significant digits used in computation is
>   usually larger than the specified number.

Let's look at the source to see what's going on.  [BigDecimal_new](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/63ee970ffb51aa64dbad02e7d5c638c52d004ae7/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L2475)
extracts the parameters, does some limit and type checking, and calls
VpAlloc.  *mf* holds the *digits* argument to BigDecimal::new:

```
return VpAlloc(mf, RSTRING_PTR(iniValue));
```

In [VpAlloc](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/63ee970ffb51aa64dbad02e7d5c638c52d004ae7/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L3908), *mf* gets
renamed to *mx*:

```
VpAlloc(size_t mx, const char *szVal)
```

The very first thing MxAlloc does is to round *mx* (the precision) up to
the nearest multiple of BASE_FIG:

```
mx = (mx + BASE_FIG - 1) / BASE_FIG;    /* Determine allocation unit. */
if (mx == 0) ++mx;
```

BASE_FIG is equivalent to [RMPD_COMPONENT_FIGURES](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/63ee970ffb51aa64dbad02e7d5c638c52d004ae7/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.h#L106), which has a platform
dependent value of either 38, 19, 9, 4, or 2.

There are further computations with mx before it is stored in the
BigDecimal being created, but we can already see that the original
argument passed to ::new is destroyed and not recoverable.